# Buffer gives ERROR 000735 in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, buffer, error-000735

I'm trying to create a buffer as part of a code but I keep getting the following error:

> ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR
>   000735: Distance [value or field]: Value is required Failed to execute
>   (Buffer).

I set the buffer distance in the script toolbox in ArcGIS but it doesn't seem to recognise it. Here is the code I'm using:

```
in_features = "Thames"
out_feature_class = "Flood_R_A"
# Run the Buffer Tool
arcpy.Buffer_analysis (in_features, out_feature_class, arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5), "FULL", "ROUND", "ALL", "")
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get if you do `arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5))`? It appears to be blank.

Comment: How are you defining your workspace?

Comment: @Aaron, I first define my workspace using GetParameterAsText to a folder and then I create a gdb in this folder. I then do this: arcpy.ResetEnvironments()
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Birkbeck_Python/Prog_Assign_1.gdb" to set it to the created gdb. It works fine until it hits the  buffer!

Comment: @Paul, I could be pure stupid but I tired adding what you said above into the code so it looked like this: arcpy.Buffer_analysis (in_features, out_feature_class, arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)), "FULL", "ROUND", "ALL", ""). It didn't bring up any additional error. Perhaps I've got the wrong end of the stick?

Comment: No, I meant add that line completely separate of buffer(). It will print out the value of the parameter. Since your error message deals with distance, the error should be with the parameter.

Comment: @Paul, I'm running this in a script in an ArcGIS toolbox. I added it as a line of code under the buffer tool but no new error message came up. Maybe I'm still confused?

Comment: Add it before. You shouldn't get an error message from that line because all it's doing is printing the value of parameter 5. You should see the whatever it is you inputted printed out in the tool run time window. What is that value?

Comment: @Paul, maybe I'm doing something wrong. It doesn't appear to be bringing up any additional message?

Comment: Are you positive you are passing a value to parameter 5? It still sounds like the parameter is blank. If you don't see a message, it could be printing a blank line.

Comment: @Paul: I think so, in the script tool I have: workspace, 4 shapfiles and a buffer distance whose data type is 'Linear Unit'. Not really sure where to go from here? Thanks

Comment: Does buffer work if you hardcode a distance (e.g. `"5 meters"`)?

Comment: @Paul, Yes, is a hardcode "300 meters" it works like a charm

Comment: This question seems to be a continuation of an earlier one from you for which you have not yet accepted an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your error message (and subsequent comments), I think the problem is with parameter 5 (which is actually parameter 6 because the counter starts at 0, not 1).

There are a few possibilities:

- You are grabbing the wrong parameter or possibly no parameter at all.
- You are failing to pass a parameter (maybe it is set as optional).
- You are passing an invalid paramater.